# Selecting a word on the cursor in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was using Vs Code, where I placed my cursor on work and pressed `ctrl + D` and it selected that word and on continuously pressing `ctrl + D` it finds the same word and select them to

**Is there any way to do that in Android Studio, maybe there is but I am not able to find it In the keymap settings**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press `Alt + J` in android studio to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio or any other IntelliJ IDEs, combination of `ctrl + w` should do the trick